# Invalid Credentials on Here Rest API

Tags: here-api

I have started to move some mapping functionality from Google to Here and have been successful on converting to displaying maps via Javascript. When I'm calling the geocoding API via rest within PHP, I'm receiving the following error:

invalid credentials for xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

My PHP Test code is very simple and is using the same App Id and App Code as I'm using for javascript maps. With or without domain restriction enabled I receive the same credentials error. Same if the URL is entered in a browser using the correct Id & Code with the domain restriction off. Any idea on what to consider?

Here's the PHP test code with my id and code replaced with x's & y's:

```
$service_url = 'https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=xxxxxxxxx&app_code=yyyyyyyyy&searchtext=Brooklyn%20NY';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curl_response;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check a similar post [Convert terminal cURL command to PHP cURL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288492/convert-terminal-curl-command-to-php-curl-request) on settings parameters in PHP curl request. If your app_id and code doesn't work then try with the demo app id to check if the problem is related to your credentials and not the php code. Also, make sure you have copied your credentials correctly in the url. If issue still issued with your credentials, try creating another project in developer site and check if your new credentials is working.

Comment: I tried the dev info and it still fails but the dev info fails with a simple copy/paste from the Here site. As an example, if I try and run the Curl command copy/pasted from https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder (no code, just curl), I get the same validation error.

curl \
  -X GET \
  -H 'Content-Type: *' \
  --get 'https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json' \
    --data-urlencode 'searchtext=200 S Mathilda Sunnyvale CA' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id=devportal-demo-20180625' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ' \
    --data-urlencode 'gen=9'

Comment: So it makes it hard to troubleshoot when copy/paste of example code produces the same error.

Comment: In my case, if I throw the curl command from the example I also get a PermissionError, however it works if I replace app_id / app_code with the ones under the freemium plan I have in my developer account

Comment: Thanks Michael. I get a permission error when I run the curl with the demo or with my own codes. Because I know the App Id and App Code work fine with all my javascript code, I wonder if there's some permission configuration at Here that is preventing the Curl from running?